# Menu Dropdowns não empurra os menus posteriores para baixo

Tags: html

Gente, sei que já tem post sobre isso aqui, porém nenhum me ajudou...
Eu tenho uma página onde será listado vários menus dropdowns, e preciso que quando um seja aberto, ele empurre os demais para baixo, para que não fique sobreposto.

Eu já tentei tudo o que foi possível, e nada empurra eles para baixo, então se alguém puder me dizer como faz e explicar o porquê (para que eu aprenda de vez), ficarei muito agradecido.

```
<div id="nav-arquivos">
                <h5>Arquivos</h5>

    <div class="dropdown" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; padding: 10px;">
      <button style="width: 900px; text-align: left; background-color: white; border: 1px solid #E6E6E6; color: #2E2E2E;" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fas fa-folder-open" style="color: #F7D358"></i> DOCUMENTOS PESSOAIS
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Ação</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another Ação</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; padding: 10px;">
      <button style="width: 900px; text-align: left; background-color: white; border: 1px solid #E6E6E6; color: #2E2E2E;" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fas fa-folder-open" style="color: #F7D358"></i> DOCUMENTOS RESIDENCIAIS
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Ação</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another Ação</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Você diz assim, amigo?
Quando se passa o mouse em cima de um dos botões, eles se tornam verticais (`display: block`).

No caso seria interessante utilizar o stylesheet e inserir um `:hover` nas divs `dropdown-item`. Desta forma:

```css
.dropdown-item:hover {
    color: blue;
    display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="nav-arquivos">
        <h5>Arquivos</h5>

<div class="dropdown" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; padding: 10px;">
<button style="width: 900px; text-align: left; background-color: white; border: 1px solid #E6E6E6; color: #2E2E2E;" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fas fa-folder-open" style="color: #F7D358"></i> DOCUMENTOS PESSOAIS
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
<button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Ação</button>
<button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another Ação</button>
<button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; padding: 10px;">
<button style="width: 900px; text-align: left; background-color: white; border: 1px solid #E6E6E6; color: #2E2E2E;" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<i class="fas fa-folder-open" style="color: #F7D358"></i> DOCUMENTOS RESIDENCIAIS
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
<button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Ação</button>
<button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another Ação</button>
<button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).